# How can I manually fetch and insert images using JavaScript and override browser resource scheduling

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to insert an image (say img1.jpg) into the DOM via JavaScript before another JavaScript (say script.js). The workflow looks like the following:

- insert the img1.jpg by creating new Image() and setting the src field. Subsequently add the image node into the DOM via document.insertBefore().
- fetch script.js via XHR and run it by calling eval() on the returned data.

The issue is that even though I have created the image before the script and set the src field, the browser is making the XHR request to the script.js before the network request for the image is sent and when I print out the resource timing, I see that the requestStart for script.js is before img1.jpg. Is there any way I can make it so that the image (or any resource for that matter) is fetched before the network request for the JavaScript (or similarly high priority resources such as CSS) is sent?

Apologies if the question is not clear. I joined the website just now.

I am adding some code here to highlight what I am trying to do:

```
const fetchObj = function( url ) {
    console.log(`fetching ${url}`);
    result = {};
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            result = this.response;
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    xhr.send();
    return result;
}

const htmlToNodes = function( markup ) {
    var template = document.createElement("template");
    template.innerHTML = markup;
    return template.content.childNodes;
}

const processAndInsertElement = function( value, index, array ) {
    var type, content;
    [type, content] = value
    if ( type == "htmlchunk" ) {
        var nodes = htmlToNodes(content);
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            document.body.appendChild(nodes[i]);
        }
    } else if ( type == "image" ) {
        document.body.innerHTML += content
    } else if ( type == "javascript" ) {
        var script = fetchObj(content);
        eval(script);
    }
}

schedule = [
            ["image", `<img src="./img/cat1.jpeg" width="500" height="auto" alt="a cute cat"></img>`],
            ["javascript", "./js/simple.js"]
            ];

schedule.forEach(processAndInsertElement);
```

In summary, I am adding the image before the script. I was hoping the image element being added to the html would cause the network fetch for cat1.jpeg to be done right away and after that the fetchObj will synchronously fetch the script and evaluate it. However, in the devtools I see that the script is being loaded first (I see it has a high priority on the performance tab) and the image is being fetched after and has a low priority.

I hope this clarifies the problem and can help reproduce it locally as well.

Comment: Hi... in order to make it easier to understand your question, I strongly recommend you to add the code you explained

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have added the code to help you reproduce the behavior. Hope that can clarify what I am asking